# Datediff, will it work if some values are 'None'

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 fields, checked in and checked out and the expression for both of them is

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CheckIn.Value), "[None]", Fields!CheckIn.Value)
```

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CheckOut.Value), "[None]", Fields!CheckOut.Value)
```

I want to calculate the duration between them in minutes, but will it affect them if some of the values are none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution here would be to use the original value, rather than the value of the textboxes here.  If your values are coming in from the dataset with `NULL` values, it'll be possible to find the difference without worrying about the expressions that format each value in the report.  The following expression should compute the difference.

```
= IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CheckIn.Value) OR IsNothing(Fields!CheckOut.Value), "[None]", 
     DateDiff("n", Fields!CheckIn.Value, Fields!CheckOut.Value))
```

This expression will result in `[None]` if `CheckIn` or `CheckOut` are `NULL` and return a numeric value representing the difference in minutes if both values are non-null values.

Comment: thanks alot, I will try it right now and will let you know if it is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work, as `DATEDIFF` requires date/datetime values, and `"[NONE]"` is a varchar/char value. Try replacing it with `NOTHING` (no quotes), which will cause the output to also be null.